# Is it possible to CTRL-z / bg; in order to background a process in a single action?

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh, background-process

Is it possible via remote ssh terminal to issue `CTRL-z` to interrupt a process already running in foreground and instantly and automatically issue a `bg` command that will fork the process in background in a single action with virtually no delay?

SSH server is running Ubuntu 18.

Comment: You mean something like `nohup COMMAND >/dev/null 2>&1 &`?

Comment: @pa4080 no, I mean the process is running in foreground and I hit a key that makes ctrl+z and bg both at the same time. I don't think it's a duplicate.

Comment: A trick to achieve that would be to define your own hotkey, which would trigger a script that runs xdotool to send these keystrokes to your remote (or local) terminal; `xdotool key ctrl+z b g enter`

Comment: I sense a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) here. What are you trying to do? Would [screen](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/screen.1.html) or one of its alternatives solve your issue?

Comment: Maybe my english doesn't allow me to go further... I mean:
"I already have a running foreground process. I'd like to background it, so I'd like to perform CTRL-z, and then bg. Can I do this in a single action: i.e. CTRL-g ?" I'm not familiar with screen, but I don't think this apply to my general question explained above!